# How to get a column based on record existence of another table in Laravel?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, backend

I'm trying to get all the cards with an additional column 'Liked' that returns 1 or 0 similar to the following MySql query.

```
select c.*
 , l.crdid is not null as liked
 from cards c
left join (
  select crdid
  from likes
  where usrid=1
) as l on c.id = l.crdid
```

This is the Laravel query I'm going to use, but not still complete

```
DB::table('cards')
->select('cards.*', 'liked')
->leftJoin(DB::raw("DB::table('likes')
    ->select('crdid')
    ->where('usrid','=',1)") as l), function($join) {
    $join->on('cards.id','=','l.crdid');
}
->get();
```

I have no idea how to get the liked column value '1' if there is a record in the 'likes' table. Can anyone please assist me in figuring out the Laravel query?

Comment: Is your SQL works? And since you're using Laravel, why don't you go with Eloquent rather than Query Builder?

Comment: Thanks. yes, my SQL works. Can you please suggest to me the best way to achieve the same result?